# Example of a metric space where inclusion is proper

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I had to prove that $ \overline{S(x, \epsilon)} \subseteq \bar{S}
(x,\epsilon)$

I took a discrete metric d on a set X with order $\geq 2$ and $\epsilon=1$

Then showed that $ \overline{S(x, 1)} \subsetneqq \bar{S}(x,1)$

However, I also have to give an example of a metric space containing a ball for which inclusion is proper.

I have thought of $[0,1] \cup \{2\}$ but I don’t know how to show that it has order $\geq 2$

Comment: Didn't you just state that the inclusion is proper for a discrete metric and $\epsilon=1$?

Comment: Both of your examples are fine. What do you mean by 'order' here?

Comment: @Berci by order I mean X contains more than one point

Comment: @Christoph yes I did but I want an example. As in what would be the X if it is discrete. In the example that i gave in the end, I’m unable to show it has more than two elements.

Comment: Well, $0$, $1$ and $2$ are three different points in $X=[0,1]\cup\{2\}$. There are infinitely many more between $0$ and $1$. So $X$ has a lot more than two elements.

Comment: @Christoph Yes exactly! So this can be an example given I take a standard distance between them and S(1,1)

Comment: Yes, the examples are fine. Did that answer your question?

Comment: @Christoph, definitely did. Thanks!